# How to add php environment variable?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

php 5.4/fcgi on apache 2.4, centos 7.1. php/apache are built/managed by cpanel easyapache.

I'm trying to add an entry to the "environment" section that displays on phpinfo()

[image]

I have tried the following :

- SetEnv in httpd.conf - it doesn't add it as an environment variable, it appears under $_SERVER
- add to /etc/sysconfig/httpd - has no effect whatsoever.
- FcgidInitialEnv MY_VARIABLE SomeValue in httpd.conf - also no effect.

Any advice appreciated. Note this section in phpinfo is NOT for showing system environment variables.

Comment: Have you tried `export PATH=$PATH:/new/folder/path` from the terminal if you're just looking to add to your path?

Comment: I'm not looking to add to the path, I'm looking to add a totally new variable.

Comment: Then you should be able to just do `export EXAMPLE=1` from terminal

Comment: I'm not talking about system environment variables, updated question to clarify this

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using `mod_fcgi` and you configured a wrapper script like this:

```
FcgidWrapper /var/www/wrapper/php72wrapper .php
```

The wrapper script `php72wrapper` then defines the environment variables when the request is dispatched to the real `php` binary - `MY_VARIABLE` has been added as example:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC="/var/www/wrapper/php72wrapper"
export MY_VARIABLE="Whatever it should contain"
exec /usr/bin/php72
```

In PHP you could access that value by e.g. using `getenv('MY_VARIABLE')`. Besides that `MY_VARIABLE` is also listed in the "Environment" section of `phpinfo()`.

An alternative way is to use `FcgidInitialEnv` in your Apache `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
FcgidInitialEnv MY_VARIABLE "Whatever it should contain"
```

see https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidinitialenv

Comment: Thanks Oliver, note that php/fcgi/apache is managed by cpanel, and there doesn't seem to be any clear way to add a wrapper script.

Comment: Search for `ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME` in the output of `phpinfo()` that's the wrapper script being used.

Comment: Updated answer by `FcgidInitialEnv MY_VARIABLE SomeValue` in your Apache `VirtualHost` configuration

Comment: Thx again, I'd already tried FcgidInitialEnv also to no avail. Updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution, the only way that works is to add a wrapper script around the calling of php, and setting the values there - thanks to Oliver Hader for the tip.